# Shared object (so) files search paths

Tags: linux, path, shared-libraries

What is the sequence of paths that are searched for loading a shared object file?

I am trying to run a executable which tries to load a shared object file. The shared object file can be found at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

I have two users, let's call them `user1` and `user2`. `user1` can run the executable but `user2` encounters the error: cannot open the shared object file: libicuuc.so

Both the users have the same `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. What is mising?

Comment: Does user2 have the correct rights to read libicuuc.so?

Comment: Yes, `user2` can read libicuuc.so.

Comment: It turns out that `user2` was trying to run a 32 bit executable for a different distro. `ldd` helped debug the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**man ldconfig** may help you

```
/etc/ld.so.cache    File  containing an ordered list of libraries found
                    in the directories specified in /etc/ld.so.conf, as
                    well as those found in /lib and /usr/lib.
```

but your distrib may contain other info than mine, so you should read yours.

Another way to decide what/which libraries are bound to your executable is to use the **ldd** program
An example:

```
ldd /bin/echo
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc2277a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003edc200000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003edbe00000)
```